# Block in serial dispatch queue not executing - GCD iOS Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I've got a for loop enqueuing blocks on to the main queue as follows:

```
  for (int x=0; x<5; x++) {
    double delayInSeconds = x * .03;
      dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
      dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        ... code here ...
      }
  }
```

Only the first block gets executed. I've verified that the loop is working properly, it is looping the proper number of times and no exceptions or error are raised.

Comment: Is the code in your block manipulating dispatch queues? Also, it appears the granularity of your delay is quite small. If timing is important, have you considered creating a new dispatch queue for this block of code?

Comment: Since this code wouldn't even compile, it's clear you didn't cut & paste it. What does your actual code look like? It's possible you have a type or some such. Also, are you sure the enqueued block never gets called? After fixing the code, it works for me (I can see the block execute 5 times).

Answer (score 6):

With this code:

```
for (int x=0; x<5; x++) {
    double delayInSeconds = x * .03;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        NSLog(@"Blah!!");
    });
}
```

"Blah" gets logged out 5 times. I'm guessing the code you posted isn't identical to the code you have in the app? I had to add the ); to the end of the dispatch_after call.